# Health Status of Nodes in CDH4 "Unknown Health"

Tags: node.js, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I have installed CDH4 on Ubuntu 12.04 using Cloudera Manager.
I have not yet configured any namenode or datanodes on it.

The health status of the nodes in the cluster when viewed under the "STATUS" tab under "ALL HOSTS" tab
Shows that the health status of all the nodes are unknown[image: Here is the screenshot of what i am seeing]

Are there any further steps i need to undergo other than the configuration of namenodes and datanodes?

Comment: If you are using any other database for cloudera manager other than derby, make sure the database service is working

Answer (score 0):

This is because the heartbeat is not coming from the agent of the particular machine to server of cloudera manager.